# Regex check valid directory path

Tags: php, regex

I'm playing around with regex, and I want to check valid folder path. This is the code.

```
return $folder->path('../../folder');
```

How to check if `../../` is valid? It can be `./../` or `.././` or ...//./`. Can it be done with regex or something else?

Comment: If you want to see whether or not it is a valid path that exists the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function should do the trick.

Comment: No, I making custom function to check that.. There is no files here.. Just some imagined folder path

Comment: What *is* and *is not* a valid path depends on your filesystem.  Unless you have some other set of rules.  Please clarify what you mean by "valid folder path"

Comment: @NicolasMarek the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function doesn't check whether there is a file, it checks whether the path is a legal path according to the operating system - file _or_ directory.

Comment: Imagined folder path is /some/folder/path or ../../folder/path. That's simple string. I want to check if ../../../ is in valid format. If it's not like .///.//.../ It may be as much as "user" wants ../../../../../ but it needs to be in this format ../

Comment: I just making custom function to check all this.

Comment: why is `.///.//.../ ` illegal?  That's a perfectly valid path afaik.  You seem to have created some arbitrary set of rules about what constitutes a valid path.  Please share those rules in your question (not in the comments), otherwise it cannot be answered

Comment: Here's the thing, the only way to test whether a path is truly valid, is to _ask the operating system if it's valid_ so that's literally what you want to use `file_exists()` for. There is no reason to do custom validation beyond that other than to tell the user that they typed the wrong path, and if you're letting users _type_ paths, then that is a potentially disastrous security exploit waiting to happen and you should invest some time in making sure they can't. Offer them a dir-tree picker instead.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, so I'm posting this here

The title of the answer is confusing. You tell about checking some valid directory. But reading the comments a more appropiate title would have been something like "Validate custom rules against a path-like string".

Where your rules seem to be (according to the comments)

1. It may start with any (or 0) number of `../`
2. Probably (need confirmation) you don't want to allow standalone `.` or `..` wihin the rest of the directory (excluding prefix)
3. The path (excluding prefix) may start as `text` or `/text`
4. Probably (need confirmation) you don't want to allow 2 or more consecutive slashes

If so, this may work for you: `^(\.\.\/(?:\.\.\/)*)?(?!.*?\/\/)(?!(?:.*\/)?\.+(?:\/|$)).+$`

**[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/880gat/2/)**